# Which Star do we see at the end of Interstellar?

Tags: interstellar

Is there a name for the star that we see at the end of Interstellar? While Cooper is exiting the Tesseract, we see a bright shining star. I was wondering if anyone knew more about it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what star you are talking about here. When Cooper exits the tesseract, he makes a short "handshake" with Amelia traveling through the wormhole in the past, and then he is put near Saturn. There is indeed a bright light on the right of Cooper fading away when Saturn comes into canvas from the left side. It is not entirely clear what light that is.

- It could just be a **visual enhancement without much significance**, somewhat of a lens effect put there for purely aesthetic purposes.
- It could as well be a visual **artefact** of the, admittedly largely unknown and mysterious, **"transportation"** that brought him there from the tesseract.
- Or, if any star at all, it would simply be ***our local* star, the sun**.

[image]
[image]

The only other thing you could be talking about are the two little lights that we see near Saturn right after that. However, notice that those lights have a regular distance form each other and are *actually blinking*. This is just the **spaceship that was sent by the nearby Cooper Station** to pick him up.

[image]

Comment: @Napoleon...I am referring to the first image posted by you. 4-5 secs into this scene, I see 2 sources of light on both sides of Cooper and the right one moves and there's a flood of bright light on Coop's face.[Could'nt post a pic for the same :( ]

Comment: @Shal Well, then see the first part of my answer, which elaborates on exactly that light.